# Popup window to remind users to change event start/end dates

Tags: date

I want a reminder window to pop up in Salesforce after a user creates an event and clicks save. Sometimes users forget to change the event start times/dates so I want the reminder to just say something like "Did you update your event start & end dates?"

Answer (score 0):

There is no great way to accomplish this. You could override the New button for a perfect solution, but creating and maintaining a Visualforce page just for a javascript:alert seems like extreme overkill.

If I received this ask from a customer, I might offer to override the View button with a Visualforce page, then simply show the alert if the record was created in the last 10 seconds (or 5 if you trust your internet connection). You could maybe get a little more fine tuned by using LastViewedDate as well, but I think this would meet your needs in almost every scenario.

```
<apex:page standardController="Activity">
    <script>
        var credt = new Date('{!Activity.CreatedDate}');
        var nowdt = new Date();
        var seconds_buffer = 10;
        if ( (nowdt.getTime() - credt.getTime()) / 1000 < seconds_buffer ) {
            alert('Did you update your event start & end dates?');
        }
    </script>
    <apex:detail subject="{!Activity.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```